# How to find preferred signature algorithm for given private key

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm using BouncyCastle to issue X509 certificates. I've found many code examples where the signature algorithm name is fixed like "SHA256WithRSAEncryption" [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/bc3b92f1f0e78b82e2584c5fb4b226a13e7f8b3b/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/cert/test/CertTest.java#L1594):

```
ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption")
        .setProvider(BC).build(privKey);
```

Is there a method in BouncyCastle or JDK to find the preferred signature algorithm name for given `PrivateKey`? Something like `getPreferredSignatureAlgorithm()` here:

```
// is there method like this?
String signatureAlgorithm = getPreferredSignatureAlgorithm(issuerPrivKey);

JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(...);
ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm)
        .build(issuerPrivKey);
X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
        .setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
        .getCertificate(builder.build(signer));
```

Comment: In golang similar functionality exists: x509.CreateCertificate() internally deduces preferred algorithm https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1858ea5d857f3a874bef131b7e1bc162d05b3366/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L1342-L1417

Answer (score 2):

Answering to my own question, I ended up simply implementing my own method like this

```
private static String signatureAlgorithm(PublicKey pub) {
    switch (pub.getAlgorithm()) {
        case "EC":
            EllipticCurve curve = ((ECPublicKey) pub).getParams().getCurve();
            switch (curve.getField().getFieldSize()) {
                case 224:
                case 256:
                    return "SHA256withECDSA";
                case 384:
                    return "SHA384withECDSA";
                case 521:
                    return "SHA512withECDSA";
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown elliptic curve: " + curve);
            }
        case "RSA":
            return "SHA256WithRSAEncryption";
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported private key algorithm: " + pub.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

Recommended message digest algorithms for EC curves are given in [RFC5480](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5480#page-9) in a table on page 9 ([errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5480&rec_status=0)).